# Mapping enum to string in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, enums

I've got a Category Hibernate model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;
```

which have a type string field. Also I've got a Java enum which represent a type of a category:

```
public enum CategoryType {
    INCOME, OUTCOME;
}
```

which I would like to use instead of the string type. The SQL accepts two distinct values in the varchar parameter: either `CategoryIncome` or `CategoryOutcome`. I would like the Category model class to accept an enum variable - and map it somehow to the string whenever hibernate asks for it.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 238, accepted):

Yes, is possible. It should be:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "category_type")
private CategoryType categoryType;
```

Comment: You can even go further and, now as JPA 2.1 is released, use `@Converter(autoApply = true) public class CategoryTypeConverter implements javax.persistence.AttributeConverter <CategoryType, String>`

Comment: For anyone who might have the same problem..: I had to put this annotation to my getter method instead of the field, like this: `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) public CategoryType getCategoryType() { return this.categoryType; }`.

Comment: I was in `hibernate.ddl-auto=update` mode and I had to drop my table and let hibernate create it again in order to convert my enum from int to varchar. Hopefully it helps someone with similar issue.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864675/hibernate-enumerated-seems-to-be-ignored if your enumeration value is being written as ordinal despite Enumerated annotation.

Comment: I do not put it on the getter.  Putting it on the variable declaration works fine, which is good for Lombok using @Data, etc.  What if I want to apply this to all Enums without annotating each one?

Comment: @Arashsoft true because hibernate won't apply the change if the column already exists

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer is not sufficient for **PostgreSQL**. I attach the implementation that worked for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64021041/5279996

Answer (score 0):

I had to add

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(30)")
```

to @dcernahoschi solutions to make it work.

```java
@Column(name = "category_type", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(30)")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private CategoryType categoryType
```

Without I got the Exception

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick. Otherwise there is no need to use two @Column annotations. It's does not work. use just one: @Column(name = "category_type", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(30)").