# Hibernate @Enumerated seems to be ignored

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, enums, hibernate-5.x

I have the class `Person` mapped with annotations with enum `Sex` reffering to the sex if is male or female. Let's see:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "SEX")
    private Sex sex;

    private enum Sex {
        M,
        F;
    } 

    // Getters, setters & constructors
}
```

When I test getting all the rows from the MySQL database, it works and the mapping is correct.

The database is already predefined, here is the column's definition:

```
`SEX` enum('M','F') NOT NULL
```

However the error occurs when I configure Hibernate with `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate`:

```
found [enum (Types#CHAR)], but expecting [varchar(255) (Types#VARCHAR)]
```

The error is a bit different (`expecting [integer (Types#INTEGER)]`) happend when I use `EnumType.ORDINAL` or no `@Enumerated` at all.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

try add  columnDefinition

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "SEX" , columnDefinition="ENUM('M','S')" ,nullable = false )
private Sex sex;
```

hibernate validate do check types , lenght.... as you have this in db level validator thinks it's different type .

I didn't see it with Oracle , but with MySql it's might be

Comment: It is verbose and it repeats the enum declaration at two places in the Java code. At this price I would not use in MySQL an enum as type  but a varchar and would add a constraint  on this column to specify the accepted values by.

Comment: Due to you map value form db into enum.in db you can update this value and your code stop work

Comment: Simply adding `@Column(columnDefinition = "enum")` appears to do the trick with H2.

Comment: Adding @Column(columnDefinition = "enum") does the trick also in the case of MySQL

Comment: Postgresql does not like @Column(columnDefinition = "enum").   any counterpart?

Comment: Postgresql likes `@Column(columnDefinition = <name_of_type>)` eg `@Column(columnDefinition = sex)`