# Hibernate column "fulfillment_status" is of type fulfillment_status but expression is of type character varying

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, enums, hibernate-criteria

I am having an issue updating enum fields in my postgres database from enums in my java entity using hibernate leading to the error in the title.

My database looks like this

```
\dT fulfillment_status
            List of data types
 Schema |        Name        | Description 
--------+--------------------+-------------
 public | fulfillment_status | 
(1 row)
```

This sets the type for a specific column fulfillment_status i.e.

```
       Column           |              Type              | Collation | Nullable |               Default                
----------------------------+--------------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------

fulfillment_status         | fulfillment_status             |           | not null |
```

Relevant sections of the java entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "payments", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"id"})})
public class Payment {
 private FulfillmentStatus fulfillmentStatus;

public enum FulfillmentStatus {
        PENDING, FULFILLED, FAILED, ABORTED
    }

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "fulfillment_status", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "enum('PENDING', 'FULFILLED', 'FAILED', 'ABORTED')")
    public FulfillmentStatus getFulfillmentStatus() {
        return fulfillmentStatus;
    }

    public void setFulfillmentStatus(FulfillmentStatus fulfillmentStatus) {
        this.fulfillmentStatus = fulfillmentStatus;
    }
```

And the code used to update the class

```
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaUpdate<Payment> update = 
        builder.createCriteriaUpdate(Payment.class);
        Root root = update.from(Payment.class);
        update.set(root.get("fulfillmentStatus"), 
        Payment.FulfillmentStatus.FULFILLED);
        update.where(builder.equal(root.get("requestID"), UUID.fromString(requestID)));
        session.createQuery(update).executeUpdate();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
```

This generates the error

```
Hibernate: 
    update
        payments 
    set
        fulfillment_status=?
2018-05-02 08:54:11 WARN  SqlExceptionHelper:129 - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42804
2018-05-02 08:54:11 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:131 - ERROR: column "fulfillment_status" is of type fulfillment_status but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 40
```

The issue here seems how to use the CriteriaUpdate to map java enum types to postgres enum types ... hopefully without creating additional mapping classes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to map postgres enum to Hibernate/JPA pojo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7603500/trying-to-map-postgres-enum-to-hibernate-jpa-pojo)

Comment: could also be caused by not having cast from enum to varchar!

Answer (score 4):

this solved my probleme :

```
@Column(name = "fulfillment_status")
@ColumnTransformer(write="?::fulfillment_status")
public FulfillmentStatus getFulfillmentStatus() {
    return fulfillmentStatus;
}
```

Comment: You saved my night ^^. In my case I still had to add `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` annotation (in Kotlin).