# JPA enum (java.lang.ClassCastException: org.postgresql.util.PGobject)

Tags: postgresql, jpa, enums

I try to use @Enumerated annotation fot mapping my enum type, but getting follow error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.postgresql.util.PGobject cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

What i do:
in postgres

```
create type "test_type" as enum ('test_1', 'test_2);
```

in java

> public enum TestType{ test_1, test_2 }
>
> @Entity @Table(name="test_table") public class TestTable {  ...
>   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)  @Column(name="col")  private TestType
>   col;  ... }

Comment: This is one of the costs of using a database access layer that tries to be database-agnostic. It often can't use the full capabilities of the underlying database engine. In the case of enums you can write persistence-provider-specific datatype-converters or use provider-specific extension annotations like EclipseLink's enum mappings, but of course it'll only work on that persistence provider. See eg http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/EnumToCode#How_to_Map_Enum_to_Coded_Values and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898369/mapping-java-enum-on-postgres-enum-with-eclipselink

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JPA enums can be persisted as a text (name of the enum) or as a numerical value (ordinal of enum). `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` tells that you prefer to persist name. Consequently database type should be varchar. Your JPA provider is not aware of PostgreSQL enums.