# PostgreSQL, enum, JPA, EclipseLink

Tags: postgresql, jpa, enums, eclipselink

I wonder how to map with JPA Java enum and PostgreSQL enum type ?

In PostgreSQL side I have created this type :

```
CREATE TYPE langage AS ENUM ('FR', 'EN', 'DE');
```

And I have a Java enum :

```
public enum LangageEnum {   
   FR,
   EN,
   DE;
}
```

My JPA entity field is this one :

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name="langage")
private LangageEnum langage = LangageEnum.FR;
```

but I receive Exception :

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERREUR: la colonne « langage » est de type pretoria.langage mais l'expression est de type character varying
>     Indice : Vous devez réécrire l'expression ou lui appliquer une transformation de type.

I think I can succeed using `ObjectTypeConverter` as show [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/EnumToCode)

but `ObjectTypeConverter` is a `EclipseLink` annotation, not `JPA` so I'm looking for another way to do this.

So, how can I map Java enum to PostgreSQL enum please ?

Comment: Standard JPA doesn't support custom converters. You are out of luck if you don't want to use eclipselink specific converters, you have to use either String or Integer.

Comment: I can use EclipseLink converter. I was wondering if there was a more "conventionnel" and abstract way to do this. Thx

Comment: I can not success...Can you have some code please ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you've created an enum type in Postgres, but what about the field in a table?

This works for me:

**Enum**

```
public enum CampaignState
{
    READY,
    RUNNING,
    PAUSED,
    FINISHED;
}
```

**Entity**

```
...
@NotNull
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private CampaignState state = CampaignState.READY;
...
```

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE campaign
(
    id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
    ...
    state CHARACTER VARYING(64) NOT NULL, -- defined by application
    ...
);
```

I hope it helps.

**>> Edit**

As per your comment, please, take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145403/jpa-enum-java-lang-classcastexception-org-postgresql-util-pgobject).

Comment: But you use varchar and not the user defined type.

Comment: Yes, when using varchar in table it's work but I use enum type langage, not varchar. Thx anyway

Comment: I see your point, but there are a couple things I could mention about it. If you have an enum type defined in database and a correspondent enum in Java, you may have duplicated knowledge. Not good for maintenance at all. By defining an enumerated field with EnumType.STRING and storing it's string representation you keep the knowledge in your application. Furthermore, JPA providers should be database agnostic, so Eclipselink allows you to save an enum value as either an ordinal or string. If you're wanting to save string, varchar is the way to go. Nothing wrong with that.