# JPA 2.1 persist string as enum postgres

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, jpa-2.1

I am using JPA 2.1 to perform CRUD operations on my DB. I generated entities from a pre-existing DB using *JPA Tools -> Generate entities from Tables option*. This created a Java entity named Item.

The DB table Item has a column of type enum **`item_status`** which was created as **String type in the Java entity**. Now I am trying to insert a column into table Item using the following method and got this error

*ERROR: column "status" is of type item_status but expression is of type character varying. Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.*

Item_Test_CRUD.java

// Here I am trying to test if I can insert into the DB

```
@Test
void test_insert_into_db() {
    DBConnection conx = new DBConnection(); // here I get the message login successful, so I assume the connection to the DB is okay

    Item it = new Item();

    it.setStatus("Rework");
    it.setUpdatedAt(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    it.setMetadata("{}");

    conx.insert(it);
}
```

// I am using EntityManager to connect to the DB
DBConnection.java

```
public void insert(Object obj) {
    this.em.getTransaction().begin();
    this.em.persist(obj);
    this.em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

// Entity generated by the JPA tool
Item.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="\"Items\"")
@NamedQuery(name="Item.findAll", query="SELECT i FROM Item i")
public class Item implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Convert(converter=UUIDConverter.class)
    private String id;

    .
    .

    @Column(name="status")
    private String status;
    .
    .
}
```

Any idea what mistake I am doing here ?

Comment: this should help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43125099/270371

Comment: this helped. Thank you.

Comment: Appended *stringtype=unspecified* to connection string and was able to keep the java entity's column type as String and do a insert.

Comment: write an answer it could be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved the issue by adding *stringtype=unspecified*  to the connection string. I didn't have to change the java entity column's type to enum. Just left it as String type. 
For more information : stackoverflow.com/a/43125099/270371
https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/94/connect.html