# spring jpa query where clause with enum type matching

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm using the `spring-data-jpa` for object relational mapping with spring boot and postgreSql, and wrote custom method to get the distinct value of `task_id` column when matching to where condition

```
@Query(value = "select distinct task_id from schema_task_test.test_table where type =:type", nativeQuery = true)
public List<Integer> findDistinctTasks(@Param("type") String type);
```

But in database `type` is of `Enum` type so I'm getting execption

**Error**

```
[ERROR] 2019-03-19 16:33:45,006 http-nio-8080-exec-1 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - {} - ERROR: operator does not exist: schema_task_test.type_enum = character varying

Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: Can you add the entity class?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851758/java-enums-jpa-and-postgres-enums-how-do-i-make-them-work-together

Comment: is this possible without entity @mohammad_1m2

Comment: Native query is an other option that can be used without entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a native query you have to cast explicit to the database enum type.

> @Query(value = "select distinct task_id from schema_task_test.test_table where type = cast(:type as type)", nativeQuery = true)

You also should use the @Enumerated in the entity.

When you want to save the values as string you can use @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)