# Enum - PostgresSQL - Java Spring Boot - Hibernate - Error

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, enums

I am using Hibernate 5.3.11

I'm trying to link an Enum between my PostgresSQL database and my code.

I referred to these links to make my code :

[Hibernate mapping between PostgreSQL enum and Java enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27804069/hibernate-mapping-between-postgresql-enum-and-java-enum)

[Java Enums, JPA and Postgres enums - How do I make them work together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851758/java-enums-jpa-and-postgres-enums-how-do-i-make-them-work-together)

[Mapping a Java Enum to a database-specific Enumerated column type](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-an-enum-type-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

**Problem**

But I still have that error :

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: the column "weather" is of type weatherenum but the expression is of type integer.
>   Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

How solve this problem ?

**My code**

First, I pass through this method, a meteoDTO that I map into a meteo entity :

```java
public MeteoDTO saveMeteo(MeteoDTO meteoDTO) {

        Meteo meteo = MeteoMapper.INSTANCE.meteoFromMeteoDTO(meteoDTO);

        this.meteoRepository.save(meteo); // here, there's a error

        return MeteoMapper.INSTANCE.meteoDTOFromMeteo(meteo);
    }
```

meteoDTO :

[image]

Entity meteo :

[image]

Meteo entity

```
//package and imports

@Entity
@TypeDef(
        name = "pgsql_enum",
        typeClass = PostgreSQLEnumType.class
)
public class Meteo {
    private Integer id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "weatherenum")
    @Type( type = "pgsql_enum" )
    private WeatherEnum weather;
    ...

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer getId() { return id; }

    public void setId(Integer id) { this.id = id; }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "weather")
    public WeatherEnum getWeather() { return weather; }

    public void setWeather(WeatherEnum weather) {
        this.weather = weather;
    }

   .
   .
   .

}
```

PostgreSQLEnumType

```
public class PostgreSQLEnumType extends org.hibernate.type.EnumType {

    public void nullSafeSet(
            PreparedStatement st,
            Object value,
            int index,
            SharedSessionContractImplementor session)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        if(value == null) {
            st.setNull( index, Types.OTHER );
        }
        else {
            st.setObject(
                    index,
                    value.toString(),
                    Types.OTHER
            );
        }
    }
}
```

I tried also this code :

```
public class PostgreSQLEnumType extends org.hibernate.type.EnumType {

    public void nullSafeSet(
            PreparedStatement st,
            Object value,
            int index,
            SharedSessionContractImplementor session)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        st.setObject(
                index,
                value != null ?
                        ((Enum) value).name() :
                        null,
                Types.OTHER
        );
    }
}
```

WeatherEnum

```
public enum WeatherEnum {
    sunny, cloudy, stormy, rainy;
}
```

PgSQL Script to create enum:

```
CREATE TYPE WeatherEnum AS ENUM ('sunny','rainy','cloudy','stormy');
```

Meteo DDL:

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 10.11 (Ubuntu 10.11-1.pgdg18.04+1)
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 12.1 (Ubuntu 12.1-1.pgdg18.04+1)

-- Started on 2020-01-04 20:00:13 CET

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET xmloption = content;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

SET default_tablespace = '';

--
-- TOC entry 209 (class 1259 OID 33303)
-- Name: meteo; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

CREATE TABLE public.meteo (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    temperature integer,
    windforce integer,
    windspeed integer,
    weather public.weatherenum,
    minswell integer,
    maxswell integer,
    date timestamp without time zone,
    idcity integer
);


ALTER TABLE public.meteo OWNER TO postgres;

--
-- TOC entry 208 (class 1259 OID 33301)
-- Name: meteo_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

CREATE SEQUENCE public.meteo_id_seq
    AS integer
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;


ALTER TABLE public.meteo_id_seq OWNER TO postgres;

--
-- TOC entry 2961 (class 0 OID 0)
-- Dependencies: 208
-- Name: meteo_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE OWNED BY; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

ALTER SEQUENCE public.meteo_id_seq OWNED BY public.meteo.id;


--
-- TOC entry 2831 (class 2604 OID 33306)
-- Name: meteo id; Type: DEFAULT; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.meteo ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('public.meteo_id_seq'::regclass);


--
-- TOC entry 2833 (class 2606 OID 33308)
-- Name: meteo meteo_pkey; Type: CONSTRAINT; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.meteo
    ADD CONSTRAINT meteo_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);


--
-- TOC entry 2834 (class 2606 OID 33309)
-- Name: meteo meteo_idcity_fkey; Type: FK CONSTRAINT; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.meteo
    ADD CONSTRAINT meteo_idcity_fkey FOREIGN KEY (idcity) REFERENCES public.city(id);


-- Completed on 2020-01-04 20:00:13 CET

--
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
--
```

Comment: 1) Show how this attribute is defined in DDL. 2) Show the code where the problem occurs.

Comment: ok sorry, I'm editing my question

Comment: I don't understand  the "1)", what's DDL ?

Comment: DDL https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/Data-Definition-Language-DDL

Comment: Show full stack trace, not the last line only.