Custom Hibernate enum name in database
I have an issue to match JPA to my database schema enums.
My Postgres database holds an enum like:
CREATE TYPE segment_type AS ENUM ('SEG1', 'SEG2');

The JPA entity looks like the following:
@Entity(name = "entity_segments")
public class EntitySegment {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "my_id")
    private UUID myId;

    @Column(name = "segment_type", columnDefinition = "segment_type")
    @ColumnDefault("'SEG1'")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @JdbcType(PostgreSQLEnumJdbcType.class)
    SegmentType segmentType = SegmentType.SEG1;
}

The corresponding enum class is straightforward:
public enum SegmentType {
    SEG1,
    SEG2
}

Everything works fine if I create the database schema using (Flyway) SQL scripts. However, if I disable Flyway and let JPA create the entities and run the service, JPA complains about missing segment_type because it created a segmenttype enum:
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: type "segment_type" does not exist

How can I tell JPA to use/create the database enum segment_type instead?

I think this is not possible, you have to create the enum before creating your table, as an approche you can create the enum even by flyway as you do or by DDL script

check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851758/java-enums-jpa-and-postgres-enums-how-do-i-make-them-work-together
